# Queryset across fours models

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Using four models, in a single database,  and I would like to count the total number of employees on a course.

This working code currently calculates:

1. The Course name, i.e Course01, Course02
2. The number of unique Courses, i.e 2 courses
3. The number of instances of each course i.e. Course01 = 3, Course02 = 1, Total courses = 4

**models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    surname     = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class CourseDetail(models.Model):
    course      = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    date        = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    renew_date  = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    attendance  = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='CourseDetailAttendance')

class CourseDetailAttendance(models.Model):
    course_details = models.ForeignKey(CourseDetail)
    employee       = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

I would like to return the total number of candidates that a each unique course group, i.e. Course01 = 24 candidates

What I have so far...

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Count

def BetweenDates(request):
    start_date = '2013-03-01'
    end_date = '2013-03-30'

    cr = CourseDetail.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
    cc_count = cr.count()
    cc_grouped = cr.values('course__name').annotate(Count('course'))
    cc_grouped_count = cc_grouped.count()

    cc_attendance = ???????????

    context = {"cc_grouped_count": cc_grouped_count, 
            "courses_grouped": cc_grouped, 
            "date_range": cr, 
            "courses_count":cc_count, 
            "cc_attendance": cc_attendance,
            }
    return render_to_response('between_dates.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**between_dates.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<h4><p>{{ cc_grouped_count }} courses delivering {{ courses_count }} course instances between {{ startdate }} and {{ enddate }}</p></h4>
    {% for cs in courses_grouped %}
    <div class = "news-articles ingrid in-thirds">
        <div class = "unit">
        <div class= "box">
            {{ cs.course__name }}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "unit">
        <div class= "box">
            {{ cs.course__count }}
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "unit">
        <div class= "box">
            total number of candidates goes here {{ cc_attendance }}
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that by course group you mean a Course on a given day (CourseDetails -instance), and that you would like to query it by course name and date:

```
course_details = CourseDetail.objects.get(course__name='Django 101', date='2013-03-01')
cc_attendance = CourseDetailAttendance.objects.filter(course_details=course_details).count()
```

If you want to have the attendants of a given course, no matter when they are participating, run

```
course_details = CourseDetail.objects.filter(course__name='Django 101')
cc_attendance = CourseDetailAttendance.objects.filter(course_details__in=course_details).count()
```

To get the number of participants, during a certain time frame:

```
course_details = CourseDetail.objects.filter(course__name='Django 101', date__range=[start_date, end_date])
cc_attendance = CourseDetailAttendance.objects.filter(course_details__in=course_details).count()
```

BTW, is it possible to have the several instances of a given course (for example Django 101) on the same day? If not, I suggest you make the combination unique:

```
class CourseDetail(models.Model):
    course      = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    date        = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    renew_date  = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    attendance  = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='CourseDetailAttendance')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('course', 'date')
```

Comment: Thank you skoll.  In the template  I have this code to display the course name and instances of said course.
{% for cs in courses_grouped %}
{{ cs.course__name }}
{{ cs.course__count }}
Is it possible to get you working code with this loop, please?
I've been playing around with the python shell but I cannot create a solution.

Comment: What is it, that you try to do exactly? And what's the problem?

Comment: From my db, my current code returns a list of unique course names (15) and number of courses (27) for the particular month. What I cannot get is the number of guys trained in the each of the 15 courses. Your code works brilliant for a named course but I cannot manage to get it to work for course group set.  What do you think?

Comment: If by course group you mean instances of the Course -model, then doesn't my second example do exactly what you need? If not, please explain in terms of model names, what do you mean exactly by course group.

Comment: Say for instance a course is Django 101. There has be 3 instances of Django 101. Suppose Django 101_A on Monday with 5 guys, Django 101_B on Tuesday with 5 guys, Django 101_C on Wednesday with 5 guys. Hence you would have unique Course Name (Django 101) = 1, course instances (Django 101) = 3 and trained guys (Django 101) = 15.  Do that make sense?  I cannot understand how to access CourseDetail_Attendance through CourseDEtail.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))

Comment: So you want the number of participants to a certain Course (not course instance aka. CourseDetail), during a certain time frame? See the update to the answer.

Comment: Should I move to 'chat' as suggested by Stackoverflow (I'm really newbie)? I added what I am trying.